# Rasa ReminderScheduled makes the program crash, error with timezone

Tags: python-3.x, timezone, scheduler, rasa-core

I tried to use Rasa's ReminderScheduled as specified in the docs. I'm using Windows 10 with the Ubuntu subsystem to run the code. The code that calls the reminder is the following:

```
export_timeout = datetime.timedelta(seconds=30)
class ActionGiveListProducts(Action):
    def name(self):
        return 'action_give_list_products'

    def run(self, dispatcher, tracker, domain):
        s = getInfo("listeproduits")
        dispatcher.utter_message(s)
        return [ReminderScheduled("action_export_logs", datetime.datetime.now() + export_timeout)]
```

Executing this Action causes the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                        
File "bot.py", line 136, in <module>   
run()                                                                                                                 
File "bot.py", line 108, in run agent.handle_channel(ConsoleInputChannel())                                                                           
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/rasa_core/agent.py", line 126, in handle_channel                             
processor.handle_channel(input_channel)                                                                               
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/rasa_core/processor.py", line 60, in handle_channel                          
input_channel.start_sync_listening(self.handle_message)                                                               
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/rasa_core/channels/console.py", line 52, in start_sync_listening             
self._record_messages(message_handler)                                                                                
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/rasa_core/channels/console.py", line 45, in _record_messages                 
self.sender_id))                                                                                                      
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/rasa_core/processor.py", line 83, in handle_message                         
self._predict_and_execute_next_action(message, tracker)                                                               
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/rasa_core/processor.py", line 262, in _predict_and_execute_next_action       
dispatcher)                                                                                                           
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/rasa_core/processor.py", line 312, in _run_action                            
self._schedule_reminders(events, dispatcher)                                                                          
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/rasa_core/processor.py", line 296, in _schedule_reminders                    
replace_existing=True)                                                                                                
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/apscheduler/schedulers/base.py", line 413, in add_job                        
'trigger': self._create_trigger(trigger, trigger_args),                                                               
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/apscheduler/schedulers/base.py", line 907, in _create_trigger                
return self._create_plugin_instance('trigger', trigger, trigger_args)                                                 
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/apscheduler/schedulers/base.py", line 892, in _create_plugin_instance        
return plugin_cls(**constructor_kwargs)                                                                               
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/apscheduler/triggers/date.py", line 20, in __init__                          
timezone = astimezone(timezone) or get_localzone()                                                                    
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/apscheduler/util.py", line 86, in astimezone                                 
    'Unable to determine the name of the local timezone -- you must explicitly '                                        
    ValueError: Unable to determine the name of the local timezone -- you must explicitly 
specify the name of the local timezone. 
Please refrain from using timezones like EST to prevent problems with daylight saving time. 
Instead, use a locale based timezone name (such as Europe/Helsinki).
```

I tried to set the timezone in the launch code as following:

```
os.environ['TZ'] = 'Europe/London'
time.tzset()
```

but this didn't change anything. I also searched for other solutions, but found nothing relevant. 
Does someone know what causes this error exactly and if there is way to eliminate it?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you run this in a Linux environment (as I had the same error), so try to set the following:

keep as you had it in the python code:

```
keepos.environ['TZ'] = 'Europe/London'
```

and also set the timezone in the os:

```
sudo cp /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/London /etc/localtime
```

It worked for me.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer, but this didn't seem to work for me (I still have the exact same error). I am using the Ubuntu subsystem for windows, maybe this is preventing something from being configured the right way.

Comment: @CharlotteJunod do you find any solution. I have the same problem now.

Comment: Depending on the number of classes/files you run and the order that you run them you need to make sure your python included the line I mentioned earlier. I usually get this error if I mess the order up. Otherwise is working fine (tried on Ubuntu subsystem for windows too)

Answer (score 0):

The following works on the Ubuntu subsystem for Windows:

```
sudo cp /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/New_York /etc/localtime
TZ=America/New_York rasa x
```

You can also make the `TZ` environment variable permanent by adding `export TZ=America/New_York` in your `~/.bashrc` file.